# Create Spark dataframe from groupby and known sequence vector

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Value  |
|------|------|--------|
| Key1 | Key2 | 45.0   |
| Key2 | Key2 | 34.0   |
| Key2 | Key3 | 121.0  |
```

and I have the sequence of values `[1,2,3]`. I would like to generate the following dataframe

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Value  |
|------|------|--------|
| Key1 | Key2 |  1     |
| Key1 | Key2 |  2     |
| Key1 | Key2 |  3     |
| Key2 | Key2 |  1     |
| Key2 | Key2 |  2     |
| Key2 | Key2 |  3     |
| Key2 | Key3 |  1     |
| Key2 | Key3 |  2     |
| Key2 | Key3 |  3     |
```

The pairs of `(Col1,Col2)` are generate from a groupBy and, in my new dataframe, I would like each pair returned by the GroupBy to be repeated three times, once for each value of the sequence. I will then use the combination of `(Col1,Col2,Value)` to left join that dataframe with another one.

One solution I have thought about could be to take the union of three different dataframe, each of them with rows containing distinct `(Col1,Col2)` with the given value of the sequence, that is

```
df.groupBy(['Col1','Col2']).agg(F.lit(1).alias('Value')).union(df.groupBy(['Col1','Col2']).agg(F.lit(2).alias('Value')))
```

I would like to find a more elegant solution as this one looks very similar to what I would do in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a literal array column and explode it:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("Key1", "Key2", 45.0), ("Key2", "Key2", 34.0),
    ("Key2", "Key3", 121.0)], ("Col1", "Col2", "Value"))

values = [1, 2, 3]
df1 = df.withColumn("Value", F.explode(F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in values])))

df1.show()
#+----+----+-----+
#|Col1|Col2|Value|
#+----+----+-----+
#|Key1|Key2|    1|
#|Key1|Key2|    2|
#|Key1|Key2|    3|
#|Key2|Key2|    1|
#|Key2|Key2|    2|
#|Key2|Key2|    3|
#|Key2|Key3|    1|
#|Key2|Key3|    2|
#|Key2|Key3|    3|
#+----+----+-----+
```